# The first time I close a fold, it closes all folds

Tags: vim

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldnestmax=3
set nofoldenable
```

When I open a file, nothing is folded, as expected. The first time I close a fold using <kbd>zc</kbd>, it closes *all* possible folds recursively. Then I issue <kbd>zR</kbd> and it reveals them all, and then <kbd>zc</kbd> behaves as expected, closing one fold at a time. It appears that <kbd>za</kbd> behaves the same way; the first time it folds everything, every time after that it folds one thing.

Is there a way to make <kbd>zc</kbd> always close a single fold? I'm basically trying to eliminate the "close everything, and then reveal everything" step that I have to do any time I want to fold something.

Comment: za work using you options and a java buffer in vim 7.2 on my Ubuntu 10.10. What language are you using? Sometimes it closes the whole class if the current line is not recognized as a block.

Comment: Ruby. Python and PHP don't fold at all ("E490: No fold found"), and Java exhibits the same behavior as Ruby. Those are the only four languages I've tried so far. My dotfiles are [here](https://github.com/tsigo/dotfiles/tree/master/vim) if you think something else might be interfering.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens is that pressing <kbd>zc</kbd> will turn on folding (see `:help zc`), and this will make Vim apply `'foldlevel'` which is 0 by default (meaning all folds will be closed). So if you set `'foldlevel'` to a high value in your vimrc it should work as expected.

Comment: If you use foldnestmax then setting foldlevel to the same value is high enough.